# Net Core Signalr Console Client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-core

I know there is package for ASP .NET Core for the server: Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server. Is there the same package for the client side?

Answer (score 0):

An alpha version of SignalR for ASP.NET Core shipped yesterday. This is the first official release. It contains the server component and managed and JavaScript clients. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) is the announcement that shows how to get started.